# Object in foreground when in a function

Tags: android, iphone, ios, lua, coronasdk

I you all, I'm having troubles when I try to insert an element in my program (made with Corona SDK so using LUA).

The problem is that when I insert an object in a function, it appears in foreground, even in i declare in my code another object after the one in the function

for example, if I write

```
local function obD()

local obD = display.newRect(_W-30, _H/2+160, 10, math.random(-140, -20))
localGroup:insert(obD)
obD.isFixedRotation = true
obD:setFillColor(255, 0, 0)

end

tmrD = timer.performWithDelay(1500, obD, maxOb)


local myText = display.newText("Hello World", _W-30, 310, "PUSAB", 8)
localGroup:insert(myText)
```

the object supposed to be in foreground would be myText, but insted appears obD, while if I write

```
local obD = display.newRect(_W-30, _H/2+160, 10, math.random(-140, -20))
localGroup:insert(obD)
obD.isFixedRotation = true
obD:setFillColor(255, 0, 0)

local myText = display.newText("Hello World", _W-30, 310, "PUSAB", 8)
localGroup:insert(myText)
```

myText appears as it should (appears in foreground)

What can I do to fix this issue? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You use `performWithDelay`, which delays execution of a function. This causes `localGroup:insert(obD)` to be executed after `localGroup:insert(myText)` is executed, which puts it in the foreground.

You can change the first insert to `localGroup:insert(1, obD)` to "force" its index and put it  in the background. See [GroupObject](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/GroupObject/insert.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use (as Paul suggested):

```
localGroup:insert(1, obD) -- This will make `obD` z-index to 1
```

or:

```
myText:toFront()  -- This will force the index of `myText` to the highest value/force forward
```

**Note:**

- Call any of these methods only after creating `obD` (as per your code).
- While using the second method, make sure that you declare `myText` in global preference.
  (ie., you have to declare myText as `local myText` in the top of your scene).

Keep Coding............... :)

Comment: @luaLover: If you have succeeded to solve your problem, then mark any of the answer as accepted...